# Profile does not have permission to Visualforce page but User able to access it

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, sharing-rule, content-security-policy

We have a bunch of Visualforce pages which are not supposed to viewed by some profile users. But they have access to the objects and field level access to all the objects involved in that VF page because they need to view the details in other components. We have removed the Visualforce pages from profile. But the users are still able to access the VF pages that we have removed. This is happening in target org where we have installed MANAGED package. Wherever I check for the solution, everyone is saying to go to Profile -> Visualforce pages and remove the VF page access. That's what exactly we did but the user still able to access the pages. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: does the user have assigned permission sets that are giving them VF page access?

Comment: No. Zero permission sets assigned to the user.

Comment: do users have `permission set groups` assigned?

Comment: No cropredy. I have taken a clone of standard user profile and tried with a new user with no assignments..